# Consuming exact number of events from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Naturally, streaming apps are unbounded, but I have a new use case where I need to consume an exact number of messages or less (configurable, for example, 100 messages) from a Kafka topic. Then the app should stop.

The motivation is very simple, the flow is rarely used and no need for real-time, so there is no reason to have a permanent streaming app.

It is enough to invoke the app once in a while.

Is there a way to implement it using FlinkKafkaConsumer?

Adding a counter that will kill the app when it reaches the required number of messages is an option, but I prefer to use something more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a wrapper SourceFunction for the FlinkKafkaConsumer, which delegates to it, and terminates when the target number of messages have been read. When all of the sources of a Flink streaming job are done, the workflow will automatically stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `max.poll.records` to 100 and set adjust `fetch.max.bytes` to the number equal to the size of 100 messages. Eg: 1 mess = 10bytes => `fetch.max.bytes` = 100*10bytes

Comment: Thanks for your answer, a few questions:
if I don't know what is the message size, can I just set max.poll.records?
Does the app will stop after consuming the number of jobs?
If there are fewer messages in the topic then the max.poll.records value, how can I automatically stop the app?

Comment: max.poll.records does not work alone without fetch.max.bytes. If you can't provide the exact number for fetch.max.bytes then it may lead to not having the exact messages consuming at once. For stopping the app, i think a checker for messages size is not a bad idea

Comment: So I would need to implement counter anyway and this is exactly what I am trying to avoid :(

Comment: not actually a counter which is counting everytime, it only needs to count when the consumer reads the amount of messages < the maximum amount you want. If at a time consumer fully reads 100 messages, you can stop the app right after.